# MySQL ORDER BY, GROUP BY within a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've been searching for a while and couln't find an example that worked. Hopefully you can spot the glaring mistake!

```
SELECT
        Timestamp
        , i_currency.Code AS Code
        , Conversion
    FROM
        i_convert(
            SELECT
                Timestamp
                , Conversion
            FROM
                i_convert
            ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
        )
        JOIN i_currency
            ON i_convert.CurrencyID = i_currency.CurrencyID
    GROUP BY Code
```

I'm not sure wherer the JOIN should be, should it be in the parentheses, outside or both? I've tried all three with no luck, keep getting:

```
You have an error... ...near '( SELECT Timestamp , Conversion FROM i_convert ORDER '
```

Comment: @Strawberry: I think this should be the alias name.

Comment: @Strawberry There is no such function. He wants to use it as an alias for SELECT result. Look here: `ON i_convert.CurrencyID = i_currency.CurrencyID`

Comment: I think that was berry flavored sarcasm. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original query doesn't make sense.  It is using `GROUP BY`, but attempting to select columns that are neither grouping columns nor aggregate functions of the groups.  Which Timestamp and which Conversion are expected for any given result row?

I suppose the objective is to select the most recent conversion for each currency.  That might look more like this:

```
SELECT
    latest.Timestamp AS Timestamp
    , i_currency.Code AS Code
    , i_convert.Conversion AS Conversion
FROM i_currency
    JOIN i_convert
        ON i_convert.CurrencyID = i_currency.CurrencyID
    JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(Timestamp) as Timestamp, CurrencyId
        FROM i_convert
        GROUP BY CurrencyId
    ) latest
        ON i_convert.Timestamp = latest.Timestamp
            AND i_convert.CurrencyId = latest.CurrencyId
```

Comment: Bingo, you nailed it. Thanks a lot!